# raycaster.intersectObjects returns 0 always

Tags: three.js

Below is the code that i am currently experimenting with, raycaster.intersectObjects returns 0 always what am i missing here? I have also tried raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

geometry.vertices.push(vertex);

objects.push(geometry);

var particleTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/test.jpg');
                var materials = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
                    map:particleTexture,
                    size: 150
                    });

document.addEventListener('click', onDocumentMouseClick, false);

function onDocumentMouseClick(event) {

```
event.preventDefault();

var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();


vector.set( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 ); // z = 0.5 important!

vector.unproject( camera );

raycaster.set( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );

}
```

particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, materials);

scene.add(particles);

Comment: Is your scene window.innerwidth by window.innerheight when it comes to size?

Comment: The camera aspect is defined as camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight; is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I meant when you call renderer.setSize(x,y) what are your parameters? If they aren't window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight then I can give you a good answer

Comment: for renderer.setSize i am passing window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth

Answer (score -1):

You can intersect from `Array`, scene.childern is `Object`.

Try to make another array reference to inersected object.

```
    function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {  
            event.preventDefault();
            mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    }

    function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {
     event.preventDefault();
     if(event.which == 1)  { /// LMB
                           var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera ); 
                           raycaster.params.Points.threshold = 100000;   

                    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( intersects_obj, false ); 
       console.log(intersects_m);
     }
    } 

    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    var intersects_obj = [];


    canvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );   
    canvas.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );

//var paticles = .... your code;

    intersects_obj.push(paticles);
```

Comment: Tried this too, still intersects is 0

Comment: I am sorry still the intersects_m is 0, where should the code from var mouse declaration be placed ?

Comment: in scene initialisation

Comment: Thats where i placed it, still no luck

Comment: Still intersects_m is zero :-(

Comment: The vertex i defined is like below which has only x defined, is that a problem?   geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
   
   vertex.x=(  [i + 3 ] * 140 ) - 1330;

Comment: it is code i  using in many projects, problem will neot be in there. look on your canvas HTML and CSS postition try to reverse some examples

Comment: I have been trying looking all around the web for examples and tried reversing them unfortunately none of them worked. I am still confused why the intersects is returning zero. Could you provide a link to some example that i can use?

Comment: Old but still nice https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Click.html

Comment: Tried that too, the only difference i could see that is it is using a Three.mesh, below is what i am doing => geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

vertex.x=(  [i + 3 ] * 140 ) - 1330;
vertex.y = - ( [i + 3 ] * 180 ) + 990;
vertex.z = 100; 
            
  geometry.vertices.push(vertex);


var particleTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imgstr);
    var materials = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
     map:particleTexture,
     size: 150
     });

particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, materials);

scene.add(particles);
targetList.push(particles);

Comment: You cannot intersect Points as mesh try increase raycaster.params.Points.threshold value EDITED code

Comment: My code is based on this : is it possible to show how to integrate the click event? https://codepen.io/seanseansean/pen/EaBZEY?editors=1010

Comment: I am able to intersectObjects when i use a THREE.Mesh but couldn't intersect when i use THREE.Points. Can somebody help me understand what i am missing?

Comment: For me, scene.children is an array.  The core of _my_ problem is that setFromCamera is yielding a raycaster internal direction of 0,0,0 and I can't figure out why since the camera position and mouse NDC looks fine.